# Toaster and Kettle cause my green power board to trigger

Tags: electrical, surge-suppression

I had my computer connected to a green power board.  The computer itself is on the master port and the screen, speakers, etc are on the slave ports.  When the master port drops below 5 W, ie. when the computer goes to sleep, the slave ports turn off to save power.

I stopped using this setup because I noticed my screen and speakers would occasionally pulse on and off when not in use every 4 seconds.  I'm guessing the power board takes 2 seconds to decide when to switch and the master port was floating around 5 W.

I finally realised it coincided with the operation of kitchen appliances such as the kettle and toaster.

Could my appliances be causing enough noise on the line to trip my power board?  Is so, what steps and products could I use to prevent this?  I'm happy to spend some money, but not so much that the power savings are negated.

Comment: Sounds like you have some electrical noise on the line from the kettle and toaster (as stated), This unit should have lots of incorporated EFI filtration on the input side.. I wonder if the pulse is travelling through the PC power source from the Kettle and triggering the switch? Essentially these devices are made for exactly what you are using it for, so its either your earthing in the home or a faulty unit.

Comment: It is likely that there is a sag on the line voltage just as the toaster or kettle comes on. I am going to guess that some crappy design in your "green board" has some sensitivity and threshold shifts that occur when the line voltage sags causing it to make inappropriate state changes. Best suggestion is to try plugging the "green board" into a completely different circuit than the toaster and kettle.